# ActionBarActivity content gets reset when orientation changed - DrawerLayout

Tags: android, android-actionbar, drawerlayout

I've been searching  around for this solution over this site, but it seems I can't resolve this problem anyhow. Basically I created slide menu in ActionBarActivity, when one of the items (constructed from ListView ) on the slide menu clicked, it shows the value to a TextView. But when orientation changed (phone rotated) the content got reset. I'm on API level 19 (KitKat)

All codes:

```
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {



   private TextView textview;
    private ListView navList;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private String mActivityTitle;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        navList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.navList);
        textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
        isiElementList(); // isi elemen2 list, dan add masing2 click event.
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mActivityTitle = getTitle().toString();
    }
    private void isiElementList() {
        String[] osArray = {"Android", "iOS", "Windows"};
        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, osArray);
        navList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        navList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String text = navList.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                textview.setText(text);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Activate the navigation drawer toggle
        // Pass elemen2 ListView ke Drawer
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I tried:

```
 @Override
 public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
 }
```

Also:

```
 @Override
 public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
     super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 }
```

Didn't work, some other solutions also tried but no luck. Thanks

Comment: You need to save last selected item in onSaveInstanceState and react accordingly in onCreate. Whatever you do avoid onConfigurationChanged and android:configChanges, its usually bad practice coming from misunderstanding how the system works...

Comment: Thanks but I'm not sure how I do it, i'm relatively new to Android UI, from swing background... :\

Comment: Its alright just store the selected index or id and call the onItemSelected method (the names different but you get the point) in onCreate. Google onSaveInstanceState, youll surely find a good tutorial.

Comment: @EugenPechanec, I just posted entire codes..

Comment: Great! Me too, check out the correct way which won't make you hate yourself half a year from now. Speaking from experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to put this in your manifest xml for Activity:

```
<activity 
  android:name=".SomeActivity"
  android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout"/>
```

For updated question you did not initialize your mDrawerToggle in onCreate() activity method :

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);                    
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }
        };
```

More info here :

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#ListItemClicks

Comment: Logcat says you need to init your view variables after any call to setContentView. But that wont solve your reset problem.

Comment: when phone rotated it produced `java.lang.NullPointerException`, refers to  `mDrawerToggle.syncState();`, though now I commented the line it's still crushing..

Comment: can you post the code where you create your drawer/side menu?

Comment: Where do you initialize your mDrawerToggle? It should be done in onCreate() method in activity.

Comment: That's what I'm wondering because it's being fine without instantiation, the code I reduced from complex codes.. but fine..

Answer (score 1):

Android doesn't remember which item you selected when you rotate your device. You have to make it remember the item and react accordingly when the Activity is recreated.

In this example I used the selected item index since the database (mAdapter's array) does not change - the indices are stable.

```
private int mSelectedItem; // We remember the selected item index here until config change.

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Setup new layout based on current configuration.
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // Load view variables after setContentView call.
    navList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.navList);
    textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mActivityTitle = getTitle().toString();

    // Setup database.
    isiElementList(); // isi elemen2 list, dan add masing2 click event.

    // Recreate state if applicable.
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // Get selected item index from saved state.
        int selectedItem = savedInstanceState.getInt("selectedItem", 0);
        // Do the same thing as if the item was just selected.
        onSelectedItem(selectedItem);
    }
}

private void isiElementList() {
    String[] osArray = {"Android", "iOS", "Windows"};
    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, osArray);
    navList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    navList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // React to item selection.
            onSelectedItem(position);
        }
    });
}

private void onSelectedItem(int position) {
    // Remember index of selected item.
    mSelectedItem = position;

    // Do something based on this index. Database must be ready at this point!
    String text = navList.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    textview.setText(text);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    // Persist selected item index across orientation changes.
    outState.putInt("selectedItem", mSelectedItem);
}
```

There's no `onConfigurationChanged`, this won't bite you in the ass.

Comment: This does not explain why layout get reset ecpecially onSelectedItem(selectedItem) is out of scope of problem.

Comment: Though I'm still beginner, the way the item is persisted not correct IMO, UI in android must be updated from it's own thread (just like swing), so the safe way perhaps keep the state (from previous value )of the content itself.. but Thanks I'll upvote it ..

Comment: @AngryDumbassSlapper We're not leaving the main thread in this example. What gave you this idea? Saving stuff across config changes is the precise purpose of `onSaveInstanceState`. Ever wonder why your `EditText`s remember what you typed into them? That's how.

Comment: @EugenPechanec, ah seems you're right, I've just read the documentation, it seems most of the stuff in android is pretty safe to be updated.. :D, oh and thank you, merry christmas, let both answer here help some rookies later.